# Apache on CentOS as MP3 server quickly runs out of memory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, outofmemoryerror

I am using a [HostWinds](http://hostwinds.com) CentOS 4GB memory VPS with Apache as a file server. Its sole purpose is to stream out MP3 files.

After about 10 minutes of serving MP3s to about 100 simultaneous users, **Apache runs out of memory**, eating all 4GB, and I'm unable to serve any further requests.

This is a fresh CentOS install; I haven't tweaked Apache at all. If I reboot my VPS, everything works again...until it runs out of memory a few minutes later.

**Are there any Apache settings that I could use to prevent Apache from using this much memory?** Given I don't care about web apps, plugins, caching -- nothing -- I literally just want to serve MP3 files.

Comment: Show us some actual data from your system.

Comment: Sure, what info would be helpful? Does this not sound strange to you: Apache merely serving files (no PHP, no MySQL) running out of memory?